# Using .map() with useEffect and Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to use the useEffect to grab some data from an API. I am succesful in grabbing the data but after I set my state and try to map through it I just get "Can't read map of undefined". I think the problem is that it's running my .map() code before it gets the response. i am just unsure of how to solve this

This is the api response:

```
data: {count: 87, next: "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2", previous: null, results: Array(10)}
```

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import CharacterMap from './characterMap'

const App = () => {
  let [getChars, setChars] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/`)
      .then(res => setChars(res) )
  },[]);
 console.log(getChars.data.map((e) => e))
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <CharacterMap info={getChars} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that `map` call? It just creates a new array with the same information, like `slice()` would.

Comment: well after I get the .map working I will use it to extract more data.

Comment: Gotcha. FWIW, I think you want `res => setChars(res.data.results)` or `res => setChars(res.results)` (this is after you change `0` to `[]` in `useState` so it's always an array). That would also probably be where you'd extract the data you want, rather than later. So `res => setChars(res.data.results.map(/*...*/))`.

Comment: Also, the name `getChars` makes it look like a function. Since it's data, I suggest just calling it `chars`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`axios.get` is an async function and you are trying to get the data outside of an async function which is no completed yet.

You could use `useEffect` with dependency array which is equal to `componentDidUpdate` to get the data.

Initialized the state with the same datatype that you expect, in this case we expect an array you initialized ith with empty array.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import CharacterMap from './characterMap'

const App = () => {
  let [chars, setChars] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    try{ 
      let response = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/`)
      let data = await response.json();
      setChars(data);
    } catch(error) {
       console.error(error.message);
    }
  },[]);
 // If you want to access the updated state then use this.
  useEffect(() => {
     let newState = chars.map((e) => e); // map your state here
     setChars(newState); // and then update the state
     console.log(newState);
  },[getChars]);

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <CharacterMap info={chars} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The second `useEffect` hook trigger on each `state` update and so you can get the updated `state` here.

It will also trigger a `re-render` so you can also use the `map` in return statement;

Or you could update the data on `axios` response and then set the `state`. **Recommended**

```
useEffect(async () => {
    try{ 
      let response = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/`)
      let data = await response.json();
      let newState = data.map((e) => e); // map your state here
      setChars(newState); // and then update the state
      console.log(newState);
    } catch(error) {
       console.error(error.message);
    }
  },[]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think you could use useEffect more than one time on each page for some reason!

Comment: You could add useEffect multiple time as required.

Comment: this answer is wrong and misleading: useEffect shouldn't be an async function, because an async function returns a promise, but the return value of the useEffect function is used for cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the default values as array

```
let [getChars, setChars] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score -1):

you are setting data to array `chars`. instead of that set array(`results`) that you are getting in response.

As you defined `let [getChars, setChars] = useState([]);`

```
useEffect(() => {
   function getData() {
    axios
    .get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/`)
    .then(res=> setChars(res.data.results))
    .catch(err=> console.log(err))
   }

   getData();
  },[]);
```

Comment: this answer is wrong and misleading: useEffect shouldn't be an async function, because an async function returns a promise, but the return value of the useEffect function is used for cleanup.